# How to change goto statement to improve code?

Tags: c#, goto

I am writing a C# Windows Form app. I have a label with a random word, e.g. "computer". User sees covered word, in this example: "--------". User has to guess what is this word by guessing letter by letter. I created button Hint. The button is responsible for revealing one random letter. That's code I created:

```cs
private void btnHint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    repeat:
    Random rnd = new Random(); 
    int rand = rnd.Next(corrArr.Length); 
    char letter = corrArr[rand]; 

    if (letters.Contains(letter.ToString())) //check if the random letter is already used
    {
        goto repeat; 
    }
    else
    {
        word.Text = "";

        var idx = correct.IndexOf(letter);
        wordArr[idx] = Convert.ToChar(letter);

        foreach (var item in wordArr)
        {
            word.Text += item.ToString();
        }
        count++;
        
        if (wordLen == count)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen; 
            result.Text = "Win!!";
            tb.Enabled = false; 
            btnClick.Visible = false; 
        }
    }
    letters.Add(letter.ToString());
}
```

By `goto` statement I can draw a letter again, if the previous one is already used.

I heard that I shouldn't use `goto` statement like in the beginning of code, but program works perfectly. How can I improve code?

Comment: There are (very) few good reasons for using Goto but a loop is not. (Breaking out of a deeply nested set of loops is). - Do read a 101 tutorial!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave the if/else statement and use Do While loop

[tutorialsteacher](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-do-while-loop)

```
Random rnd = new Random(); 
char letter;
do
{
      int rand = rnd.Next(corrArr.Length); 
      letter = corrArr[rand]; 
} while (letters.Contains(letter.ToString()));

 word.Text = "";

 var idx = correct.IndexOf(letter);

 wordArr[idx] = Convert.ToChar(letter);
```

And of course there is more to be improved... ;)

Comment: This won't compile, because `letter` is only valid within the loop's body

Comment: @derpirscher `char letter;` before `do` and it works

Comment: @keyboardNoob I know. But nonetheless, if something is posted as an answer it should be correct ...

Comment: @derpirscher You're right. I thought it was an "architecture" query, not a bug fix. I haven't tested it. My mistake.

Comment: @benuto I just wanted an idea, so you helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Make a loop around you check and repeat it while your random letter is still contained in the already used letters.

```
private void btnHint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    char letter;
    while (letters.Contains((letter = corrArr[rnd.Next(corrArr.Length)]).ToString()))
      ; //the loops body is left empty intentionally

    ...
}
```

An even better approach would be, having a collection of available letters, and everytime, you select one randomly, remove it from the collection of available letters. This way, you won't have to do any checks or loops

```
var availLetters = "abcdef....";

int rand = rnd.Next(availLetters.Length);
char letter = availLetters[rand];
availLetters = availLetters.Substring(0, rand) + availLetters.Substring(rand+1);

...
```